# Select Element Has been changed to Mat-Select in UI and now I'm unable to select options in dropdown

Tags: angular, selenium

```
private SelectElement options;
        public SelectElement Options
        {
            get
            {
                SelectElement options = new SelectElement(Suffix);
                return options;
            }
            set { options = value; }
        }

//suffix is the pageobject
```

Comment: are there any elements like "Select" for mat-select in Selenium and I'm facing this error "OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException : Element should have been select but was mat-select"

Comment: Please Add HTML code in question,

Comment: It's not a `SELECT` element so you will have to treat it just like any other HTML element. You click on the "dropdown" and then once it's open, you click on the desired option. Another alternative is to write a wrapper, like `SELECT`, for this type of element. The choice is up to you.

Comment: For Selenium Automation how can i write a wrapper as suggested by you